# Django don't login after change password use Abstractuser

Tags: python, django, authentication

i custom user use abstractuser

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    position=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

but when i change password user in adminpage
i can't login with login function

```
class LoginClass(View):
    def get(self,request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return render(request, 'new_template/signin.html')
        else:
            return redirect('user:view_camera')
    def post(self,request):
        username1 = request.POST.get('username1')
        password1= request.POST.get('password1')
        my_user = authenticate(username=username1,password=password1)
        if my_user is None:
            return redirect('/')
        login(request, my_user)
        next_url = request.GET.get('next')
        if next_url is None:
            return redirect('user:view_camera')
        else:
            return redirect(next_url)
```

Comment: Did you change your [`AUTH_USER_MODEL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) and does your user admin view use your custom user class?

Comment: i did, when i register new user, i can login, but if i change password, i can't login with new password

Comment: Did you implement a custom method to save new passwords? Django uses a hashing algorithm to hash the password prior to saving the password into the database.

Comment: i don't know about that, how do it ?

Comment: Take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password

Answer (score -1):

```
password = 12345678

user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)

user.set_password(str(password))

user.save()


######-######

user.set_password only str value
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).